# How to bold the particular row in CSV using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, csv

I want to bold a particular row (for ex: row 1) present in CSV file but I  cannot able to bold the row.
I imported a CSV file in a variable and used `System.Windows.Form.Label` method to bold the row in CSV file. I am unable to figure out what went wrong.

```
$c = Get-Content ".\Documents\test\test.csv"
$LabelComputer = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$LabelComputer.Text = $c | Select-Object -First 1
$LabelComputer.Font = [System.Drawing.Font]::new("Microsoft Sans Serif", 12, [System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)
$LabelComputer.Text | Add-Content ".\Documents\test\new.csv"
```

```
Number | Message | Mobile
1      | hello   | 1***6
2      |  hi     | 2**7
```

Expected: I expect the row 1 (1 hello 1**6) to be bold.

Output: Row1 is not getting bold.

Comment: See @Scepticalist answer. If you are displaying the csv in a Form it should be possible to show one line of text bolded, but then you need to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57586098/edit) your question and give us the whole code for building that form and displaying the CSV in there you have.

Comment: The formatting you create applies to the `Label` object. It is not preserved when you write the *text* of the `Label` object back to a file. Not to mention that CSV doesn't support formatting anyway.

Answer (score 1):

CSV doesn't support this - you can do it in Excel but it won't save the formatting.

If you need this kind of formatting, use xls or similar.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to do that in CSV. You could all caps the output, or you could use another format that supports text styles.